# Nokogiri/Mechanize xpath locator breaks when there is a stray start tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

I loaded a page using Mechanize:

```
url = 'http://www.blah.com'
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(url)
```

and tried to access an element using an XPath selector:

```
found = page.at('/html/body/table')
```

It returns `nil` because the HTML, which is out of my control, has an opening tag where it shouldn't be:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <tr>
    <table>
      . . .
```

The "stray start tag," as Firefox calls it, is ignored when the browser renders the page in real life (and Firefox gives me xpaths that ignore it), but Nokogiri can't see anything past that extra `<tr>`.

Is there any way to clean the HTML of hanging tags like this?

Answer (score 2):

In your example it would be:

```
page.at '/html/body/tr/table'
```

But maybe it makes more sense to just do:

```
page.at 'table'
```

Comment: The problem is that my xpath is much deeper than that and I'm getting it programmatically using firefox's js code (which ignores the extra tr). I'm trying to find a general solution, not a way to manually fix this case.

Comment: The general solution is to use the correct xpath, not the broken one that firefox gives you. Post the link if you want an example.

Comment: Don't use a browser to determine the path to a node. Browsers are pathetically like puppies and will do almost anything to render a page, including ignoring bad markup, and possibly show you the DOM _after_ JavaScript has mangled a page moving elements. Use `nokogiri` from the command-line, or `curl` or `wget` to download the page and view it in an editor. Then you'll know what the actual markup looks like.

Comment: Well, if you need Nokogiri to handle html like a HTML5 browser you can just switch to Nokogumbo. Using a browser is helpful but sometimes you need to use the Network/Sources inspector rather than Elements.

Answer (score 2):

Use a less brittle XPath query?

```
found = page.at('//table')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can clean this using Nokogiri easily:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '<html><body><tr><table><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table></tr></body></html>'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

inner_table = doc.at('//body/tr/table')
if (inner_table)
  doc.at('body tr').replace(inner_table)
end

puts doc.to_html
```

With the result being:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><table><tr><td>foo</td></tr></table></body></html>
```

If your HTML is more complex, then find some sort of marker similar to the `<body><tr><table>` node-chain, and substitute it into the code above.

Note that I'm mixing both XPath and CSS accessors. I prefer CSS for their readability, but sometimes XPath makes it easier to get at something or is more self-documenting.

Also notice that I'm using both XPath and CSS with Nokogiri's `at` method. Though Nokogiri supports both `at`, `at_css` and `at_xpath`, I rely on `at` unless I need to explicitly tell Nokogiri that what I'm using as an accessor is CSS or XPath. It's a convenience thing. The same applies to Nokogiri's `search` method.